# Change columns in data.table entails the variable that consist colnames of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Some data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3,4))

dt
#    a b
# 1: 1 3
# 2: 2 4
```

Assign column names to a variable:

```
cn <- colnames(dt)
cn
# [1] "a" "b"
```

Add a new column "c" by reference:

```
dt[ , c := 3]
```

The vector of original column names 'cn' is also updated and now includes the third variable "c":

```
cn
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Are the `colnames` linked by reference? Can someone can explain it?

Comment: Please, consider adding more information about your problem. Posting only some pieces of code is not a goof practice

Comment: Sergey, thank you for your attention ... ones need " to keep your ears open" with data.table! p.s. Thanks for the advice on the design - I will consider later. Good luck!